# WinForms как сделать реагирование на нажатие нескольких клавиш одновременно

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь сделать так,что бы изображение двигалось вверх,вниз,влево,вправо в зависимости от нажатой клавиши. Например движения вверх и вниз

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, 
    KeyEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.W) 
        { 

            y1 = y1 - 5; 
            System.Drawing.Pen myPen; 
            myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black); 
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics(); 
            formGraphics.Clear(Color.White); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 5 + x1, 150 + y1, 50 + x1, 150 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 5 + x1, 130 + y1, 50 + x1, 130 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 5 + x1, 150 + y1, 5 + x1, 130 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 50 + x1, 150 + y1, 50 + x1, 130 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 150 + y1, 25 + x1, 200 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 160 + y1, 40 + x1, 180 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 160 + y1, 10 + x1, 180 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 200 + y1, 40 + x1, 230 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 200 + y1, 10 + x1, 230 + y1); 
            myPen.Dispose(); 
            formGraphics.Dispose(); 
        } 
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.S) 
        { 

            y1 = y1 + 5; 
            System.Drawing.Pen myPen; 
            myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black); 
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics(); 
            formGraphics.Clear(Color.White); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 5 + x1, 150 + y1, 50 + x1, 150 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 5 + x1, 130 + y1, 50 + x1, 130 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 5 + x1, 150 + y1, 5 + x1, 130 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 50 + x1, 150 + y1, 50 + x1, 130 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 150 + y1, 25 + x1, 200 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 160 + y1, 40 + x1, 180 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 160 + y1, 10 + x1, 180 + y1); 
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 200 + y1, 40 + x1, 230 + y1); 
               formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 25 + x1, 200 + y1, 10 + x1, 230 + y1); 
                myPen.Dispose(); 
                 formGraphics.Dispose(); 
            }
```

Но если делать таким способом, то распознается только одна клавиша-стоит при нажатой W нажать еще и D - и изображение уже двигается только вправо. Что нужно сделать для того, что бы форма считывала нажатия нескольких клавиш? Например W+D для смещения одновременно вверх и вправо?

Comment: Проверять, не была ли клавиша отжата на keyup

Comment: Не очень понял как это можно сделать,можете на примере показать,пожалуйста?

Comment: @Александр Даже события KeyUp не нашел,разве что новый метод создавать

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/system.windows.forms.control.keyup